# Force two type union keys to be the same type

Tags: typescript

I am creating a `Props` type like this:

```
type Props = {
  currentValue: number | string | Array<string> | undefined;
  newValue: number | string | Array<string> | undefined;
  ... // other props
}
```

How can I enforce that both keys are the same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the type utility [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content) type parameter.

Then, just [intersect (`&`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) that type with your "other props":

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgJwRAdsAgigJgOQgdwDUBDAGzggB4AVAPigF4oAlCAYwHsEtKByNxMjQlyEXlAA+UXigIiKvADRQ6AbgBQ60JCgAFBBzABnRrEGoM2PETIVKKOAFsARhASSoR4AgCWKAOYe6EjEIJRevgH0UnDYEABmfhBY9ABkUADeUCjEjhAAXJ7efoEAvhrqWOykxMhQnCheUGAGxoX6hkYVLZ0AdAJIFvIQ6lBjUAD0EwB6APzqPca9sjaio+NTcwutRsu5I+OTM-NAA)

```ts
type CurrentAndNewValue<T> = Record<'currentValue' | 'newValue', T>;

type Props = CurrentAndNewValue<number | string | Array<string> | undefined> & { exampleProp: string };

declare const props: Props;

props.currentValue
    //^? (property) currentValue: string | number | string[] | undefined
props.newValue
    //^? (property) newValue: string | number | string[] | undefined
props.exampleProp
    //^? (property) exampleProp: string
```

Or, without the intermediate utility type:

```ts
type Props = Record<'currentValue' | 'newValue', number | string | Array<string> | undefined> & { exampleProp: string };
```

Comment: Great answer, however, I forgot to mention that `Props` has other keys. I have updated my question.

Comment: @AlbertoVilches I updated the answer. In the future, please be sure to include all relevant information in the original question.